# What is gRPC programming surface?

Tags: grpc

In the GPRC Concept document

http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html

The gRPC programming surface concept is mentioned without a definition. Anyone knows exactly what is gRPC programming surface?

Comment: Read it as "client/server APIs"

Answer (score 0):

Quoting their documentation:

> Starting from a service definition in a .proto file, gRPC provides protocol buffer compiler plugins that generate **client- and server-side code**. gRPC users typically **call these APIs on the client side** and **implement the corresponding API on the server side**.
>
> On the server side, the server implements the **methods declared by the service** and runs a gRPC server to handle client calls. The gRPC infrastructure decodes incoming requests, executes service methods, and encodes service responses.
> On the client side, the client has a **local object known as stub** (for some languages, the preferred term is client) that implements the same methods as the service. The client can then just call those methods on the local object, wrapping the parameters for the call in the appropriate protocol buffer message type - gRPC looks after sending the request(s) to the server and returning the server’s protocol buffer response(s).

In short, the surface is the contract between the client and the service and its realization as the clientside layer (the stub) and the serverside implementation.

Comment: So the surface consists of service interface contract definition + generated stuff supporting the contract implementation?

Comment: Yes minus the link to your underlying logic

Comment: BTW you can generalize this concept beyond RPC. The same is true of SOAP services for instance